# Sitecore Solr Index instance

Tags: solr, sitecore, sitecore8

I would like to have 2 different sitecore instance with different Solr instance on my developer PC.

What would be the best way to do it:
1. Create new instance of SOLR 
2. Somehow change index name for specific sitecore instance.

based on  [solr](http://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/search/solr/installing-solr-using-the-bitnami-apache-solr-stack/) article it seems like 1 way. For me it looks not really optimal. 
if 2 case it is other question goes on: how to specify custom SOLR index names for sitecore config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you don't need to have more than one solr instance to run multiple Sitecore instances, You only need separate Core for each instance.

1. Create a new core for the second Sitecore instance on the same Solr
   instance, you can call it "Sitecore_instance2" , then restart SOLR service.
2. In **Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Indexes.config, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Analytics.config** files, you will need to
   change the core name for each index to "Sitecore_instance2" like
   this:

   `<param desc="core">Sitecore_instance2</param>`

Comment: You should *Never* change the values directly in the Sitecore config files. Its bad practice. Configuration changes should always be done via an include file - http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2011/05/all-about-web-config-include-files-with-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms.aspx

Comment: @RichardSeal +1 Totally agree, but my answer was only focusing on how to use one Solr instance with multiple Sitecore instances.

Answer (score 1):

I have over 8 Sitecore projects on the go that are all using SOLR. Creating a new SOLR instance for each project would just be a pain and a waste of time and resources. I have a single SOLR instance setup and then set the core names via an include file.

You would want a config like this one, just add it to the include folder:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
<Sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
        <configuration>
            <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
                <index id="sitecore_master_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                    <param desc="core">"Your Core Name Here"</param>
                </index>
                <index id="sitecore_web_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                    <param desc="core">"Your Core Name Here"</param>
                </index>
                <index id="sitecore_core_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                    <param desc="core">"Your Core Name Here"</param>
                </index>
                <index id="sitecore_analytics_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                    <param desc="core">"Your Core Name Here"</param>
                </index>
                <index id="sitecore_testing_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                    <param desc="core">"Your Core Name Here"</param>
                </index>
                <index id="sitecore_suggested_test_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                    <param desc="core">"Your Core Name Here"</param>
                </index>
                <index id="sitecore_fxm_master_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                    <param desc="core">"Your Core Name Here"</param>
                </index>
                <index id="sitecore_fxm_web_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                    <param desc="core">"Your Core Name Here"</param>
                </index>
                <index id="sitecore_list_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                    <param desc="core">"Your Core Name Here"</param>
                </index>
                <index id="social_messages_master" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                    <param desc="core">"Your Core Name Here"</param>
                </index>
                <index id="social_messages_web" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                    <param desc="core">"Your Core Name Here"</param>
                </index>
                <index id="sitecore_marketing_asset_index_master" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                    <param desc="core">"Your Core Name Here"</param>
                </index>
                <index id="sitecore_marketing_asset_index_web" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                    <param desc="core">"Your Core Name Here"</param>
                </index>
            </indexes>
        </configuration>
    </contentSearch>
    <settings>
        <!--<setting name="ContentSearch.Solr.ServiceBaseAddress">
            <patch:attribute name="value">http://localhost:8983/solr</patch:attribute>
        </setting>-->
    </settings>
</sitecore>
```

Comment: Hi Richart, don't we need a patch:attribute or similar for each core? I tried didnt work. Do you have a working example?

Answer (score 1):

Although you can run multiple cores under one instance, I still like the idea of completely separating the cores for different clients.  I installed multiple instances and blogged about it [here](http://www.craigtaylor.us/2015/06/run-multiple-solr-instances-for-sitecore.html).